# Alfresco Issue: URI cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, alfresco

I'm migrating an application based on Alfresco 3.2r13 from linux/IntelliJ/Ant toward Windows/Eclipse.

Later the aimed will be to add Maven to the Eclipse project, but for now, I just want it to work.

Currently I'm facing the following issue:

I add the contentTypesModel.xml to the project, here are the first lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
<description>Example custom Model</description>
<author></author>
<version>1.0</version>

<!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
<imports>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0"
            prefix="d"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/ma0189cstr/1.0" prefix="ma0189cstr"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/ma43110cstr/1.0" prefix="ma43110cstr" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/baremesSys/1.0"
            prefix="baremesSys"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/baremes/1.0"
            prefix="baremes"/>
    <import
            uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/workflow/baremes/perimetres/1.0"
            prefix="perimetres"/>
</imports>

<!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
<!-- NOTE: The following namespace my.new.model should be changed to reflect
    your own namespace -->
<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/contenttypes/1.0"
               prefix="GPCT"/>
</namespaces>
```

When trying to Run the Tomcat Server, I got the following error trace:

```
> 23 déc. 2015 16:28:44,047  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'extension.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in file [D:\TomcatGrimoire\webapps\GrimoireMk0\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\extension\gp-models-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 11230001 Could not import bootstrap model alfresco/extension/contentTypesModel.xml
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 11230001 Could not import bootstrap model alfresco/extension/contentTypesModel.xml
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.onDictionaryInit(DictionaryBootstrap.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.bootstrap(DictionaryBootstrap.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 11230000 Failed to compile model GPCT:gpcontenttypeswfmodel
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.<init>(CompiledModel.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.compile(M2Model.java:134)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryDAOImpl.putModel(DictionaryDAOImpl.java:273)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.onDictionaryInit(DictionaryBootstrap.java:146)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: URI http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/ma0189cstr/1.0 cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix ma0189cstr
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.createLocalPrefixResolver(CompiledModel.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.constructDefinitions(CompiledModel.java:134)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.<init>(CompiledModel.java:94)
    ... 37 more
```

The file wfMA0189Constraints.xml contains the following definition:

```
<!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
<description>MA0189 Constraints Workflow Model</description>
<author>FSE</author>
<version>1.0</version>

<!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
<imports>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>

</imports>

<!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/grimoire/model/ma0189cstr/1.0" prefix="ma0189cstr"/>
</namespaces>
```

As far as I understand the error, the content of the file is not acknowledged by the tomcat server. The thing is that after a check the tomcat build does contain the file.

So I'm stuck on this error. Any hlep will be welcome.

Thanks in advance and happy holidays.

Comment: are you loading the missing content model in the spring context?

Comment: Not sure. In which file could I search if such a link is made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a spring context file deployed probably in the extension path. 
The name of the file usually ends with "-context.xml".
Look for a context file that contains the name of the content model file: you should see the definition of a bean with parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap".

If you cannot find this context file, try to find it in your source code and see how it was packaged by intellij/ant

Please find more details at:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/dev-extensions-content-models-tutorials-deploy-model.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check that as soon as I can put my hands back on code. Any idea explaining why this would work on IntelliJ and not on Eclipse ?

Comment: In my experience, it has been always necessary to use ant or maven or gradle to build a project for Alfresco. if you can post the ant file, I can have a look.

Comment: I found multiple context files with parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" but none of them is referring to wfMA0189Constraints.xml or to something that looks like he is referring to the model. 

The ant file is too big to be copy here. I was first trying to migrate without ant or maven because I though it will make things easier. If it's not possible to make it work without one of those, I will start to use them.

Comment: Okay, the file was add by a patch or via IHM to the software, so when you start from a brand new install there are not registered. I add the constraints to the config and now it works. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be caused by the order in which the content models are loaded. This might explain the difference between IntelliJ and Eclipse.

If you want to be sure about the order you can use depends-on as an attribute in the bean initialization.

If the models are in different modules you can also use module dependencies. 
See example: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-module-properties.html

Comment: Your link is related to the version 4.2, is OK to assume it's still OK for version 3.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing entry of **"wfMA0189Constraints.xml"**  model file in your context file. That is the reason Alfresco is not able to pickup that model and hence it shows prefix as unidentified prefix.

Based on your logs I see you are using "**gp-models-context.xml**" as your context file. Are you able to see entry of this model file (wfMA0189Constraints.xml) there?

Comment: No there is no entry for this model file in "gp-models-context.xml"

Comment: Yes, then you need to add it(similar to wfMA0189Constraints.xml) and restart your server.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and see if it works. But I wonder how this could work on any other environment ? I mean, with the same code, the team is publishing on 2 different tomcats.

Comment: In that you might be missing some other context file where this model is registers.Point is if you have model file you need to register it with Alfresco.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that no context files are loading the model, it is possible that the model is manually uploaded in "Data Dictionary/model".  This folder can be used to add new content models dynamically on a running instance of Alfresco.

Is it possible that someone wanted to make these constraints modifiable by end users?

Do you have an instance where the deployment worked? If yes, could you check if the model is deployed in that folder?

Comment: I checked, but didn't see a Data Dictionnary folder. Is there any other way to load a model at some point and to be able to use it without having the definition file anymore ?

Comment: The "Data Dictionary" folder has to be there. It is an OOTB folder that is automatically created by Alfresco. You need to be admin to see it.

Comment: Okay, I was searching in my linux server for this directory, not in the application. I found it indeed, and there is my models in the models sub-folder. I see there is an action "import" so I will try that to see if it solve my issue. Thank you

Comment: Ok! If the model is there, I am quite sure that at least this problem will be solved.